# Почему в js при попытке вернуть функцию с функциями, объявленных в самой главной функции, возвращается результат только последней функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Я новичок в javascript. И столкнулся с такой проблемой.

**Это мой код:**

```
function myFirstApp(name, age) {
    function showSkills() {
        let skills = ['Html5', 'Css3', 'JavaScript'];

        for (let i = 0; skills.length; i++) {
            return (`Я знаю: ${skills[i]}!`);
        }
    }

    function checkAge() {
        if (age >= 18) {
            return ('У тебя отличные шансы стать FrontEnd dev`ом!');
        } else if (age < 18) {
            return ('Неплохо, малой, что ты решил заняться программированием в столь раннем возрасте!');
        }
    }

    function calcPow(num) {
        return (`Вот его квадрат: ${num * num}`);
    }

    return (`Салам Алейкум, ${name}. Это моя первая программа!`,
            showSkills(),
            checkAge(),
            calcPow(parseInt(prompt('Введи число: '))));
}

alert(myFirstApp('Alex', 23));
```

А при выполнении его, мне на страницу **возвращает результат только последней функции**.

Не знаю, как пофиксить. Помогите пожалуйста)

**html-code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вернуть массив `return [...]`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, но теперь у меня возвращается какая-то каша из ответов функций. Как можно это исправить? То есть, чтобы выполнялось все поочередно.